# Schema not updating when publish web app from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, web-deployment, entity-framework-migrations

I am building an ASP.NET MVC EF app with code-first migrations and hosting it in Azure with Azure SQL DB.  The first time I published this, it went fine.  But since then my models changed, and my schema in the Azure DB is not getting updated to match.  When I deploy, I do have "Execute Code First Migrations" checked.  When that wouldn't work, I deleted my DB and then recreated it in the Azure portal, figuring that would trigger it getting updated.  But then that didn't work, so I set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = True in the migration Configuration.  It is STILL not working, so currently my DB in Azure has none of my tables.  HOW can I get the DB in Azure to be forced to update to match my models so the published site will work??  I did try looking for if there's a way to script the VS local DB to a Create query and execute that in SQL management studio, but couldn't find how to do that.

Comment: You did try to run the app after deployment? That's when the migration kicks in (not during the deployment process). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). You can generate a script if needed with `update-database -Script`.

Comment: VS automatically launches the website once the deployment is complete...so yes, I ran it afterward. At first (before dropping the DB), it would start just fine, but upon navigating to a page that uses new fields, I would get an error. And I tried "update-database -Script" but that just gave me an Insert query for _MigrationHistory (which is the only thing I see added in the DB after everything else I tried).

Answer (score 0):

If you have made sure that you have selected `update database` in the publish setting, and the connection string is correctc and its still not updating. Maybe the following will help for you:

I sometimes get an issue like this, it is quite frustrating, My publish file is correct and my settings are set to allow SQL updates to occur during publishing. But sometimes the database hasn't been updated and I get a nice "backing context has changed" error, sometimes the culprit is the migration table that hasn't been updated. Unfortunately the only sure way to get your databases in sync is to check what migration history they are both at, by comparing `[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]`

If your published server is missing the latest migration history, then you can generate an SQL script of that by typing into the package manager console:

`Update-Database -Script -TargetMigration [migration name]`

'migration name' should be the name of the **last** migration that your published server had, visual studio will generate sql script that can be used to bring the database up to the latest migration from that target migration.

Sometimes (though very rarely, its only happened once or twice for me) the above doesn't work for whatever reason (usually because migration files have been deleted), if that is the case then its a good idea to script the whole database, and cherry pick the sql you need from that.

`Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0`

This will generate a script for every migration, you can then cherry pick based on the changes you've made. The 'latest' changes will be closer to the bottom of the file. every migrational change will start with an if check:

`IF @CurrentMigration < '201710160826338_mymigration'
BEGIN`

You can use this to pick the bits that you need, if you do pick the SQL be sure to include the update to the migration history. It will be at the end of the if block and look something like this:

`INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
    VALUES (N'201710101645265_test', N'API.Core.Configuration', 'Some long checksum')`

Including the migration history will ensure that visual studio doesn't have the problem again.

Hope this helps.